# Universal header in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, footer

I want to create a universal header (and footer) using HTML/CSS/Javascript so that if I update it to one page, it automatically updates on the rest. I also want to be able to choose which link is showing up with the active class on it. Also, I am using bootstrap. Here are some criteria I need to meet:

- No PHP
- No Server side (must work on github pages)

Thank you in advance,

Albert

Comment: You should be able to do this with CSS - as long as you always use the same HTML on all the pages.

Comment: @user2182349 I want to be able to add a link to the header and have it update on the rest of the pages and I don't see a way to do this via CSS. Can you please clarify and/or give examples? Thank you!

Comment: Are you planning to host a site on github pages?

Comment: @user2182349 Yes, I am planning to use github pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **jQuery** to `.load` a **HTML** file:

### HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#header').load('static.html');
```

Alternatively, you could use `iframe` to load your static header. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993631/simulate-php-include-without-php) for more information regarding the available techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Jekyll, this is a tool to generate static pages, also this is how the githup page handles your own personal page. You just follow the file structure and set the layout properties in your files, then you can use the universal layout (including header, footer etc.) in your page.

Here is a link to Jekyll.[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)